# need some help to get data out of quotes and brackets

Tags: java, regex

I'm working with java URL class to read data from URLs. The problem is, i have got some strings and i wanna get rid off quotes and brackets using regex. Please help me out.

**My Input**

```
1 - alt="Shervin Champbell"

2 - alt=("Shervin Champbell")
```

**Result should be**

```
Shervin Champbell
```

I just want to get rid off these quotes and brackets. I'm trying too hard but in-vain.

**I want to get rid off alt, brackets and quotes**

ouput should be: **Shervin Champbell**

**HERE IS MY CODE**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class URLReader {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "192.168.1.10");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
        URL url = new URL("http://www.ucp.edu.pk/information-technolo
           /faculty-staff/faculty-staff.aspx");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
               //found(inputLine);
               names(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }

    static void names(String name){
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);
    if(matcher.find()){
        String abc = name.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
        System.out.println(abc);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: _I'm trying too hard but in-vain_ please post what you tried

Comment: Do you want get rid of the `alt=` as well? Is there anything else in the URL? Do you want to keep the rest, drop the rest, or just remove quotes from the whole URL?

Comment: `[^(alt=)]\"\w\"`. I'm trying this

Comment: @PeterLawrey... i've successfully filter that data out of URL. Now i want to get rid off alt, =, brackets and quotes.

Comment: @luckyali444, I highly recommend this website http://gskinner.com/RegExr/, which helps you to test your regex in real time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking of something like this regex :

```
alt=[("]*(\w*[^)"]*)[)"]*
```

The captured value is the desired output

The regex string is :

```
"alt=[(\"]*(\\w*[^)\"]*)[)\"]*"
```

Comment: @benjarobin... i just copied and pasted your suggested RE in my program and eclipse does not allow me to use it. There's something wrong with the syntax.

Comment: let me show you my code where i want to place your suggested RE but it gives syntax error message.

Comment: @luckyali444 In Java's \ is special character. It is used to create other special characters like new line `\n` or to turn off special meaning of characters like quote mark `\"` (otherwise java will treat `"` as end of String). To pass \ to regex engine you need to escape its special meaning. To do that use \\, so in this regex instead of `\w` you need to use `\\w`.

Comment: @benjarobin.... i just tried your second regex string. It helped me out for some instant. Thank you so much

Comment: @Pshemo thanks a lot. Your suggestion also worked for some instant

Answer (score 1):

http://rextester.com/replace/QYV56186 Not very robust, but works with the current examples.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really *have* to do it with regex? That seems like the hard way. Why not just:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Strings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] inputs = { "alt=\"Shervin Champbell\"",
                            "alt=(\"Shervin Champbell\")" };
        for (String input : inputs) {
            System.out.println(quotedStrings(input));
        }
    }

    public static List<String> quotedStrings(String input) {
        String[] parts = input.split("\"");
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < parts.length; i+=2) {
            result.add(parts[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Output (in braces because it's a List):

```
[Shervin Champbell]
[Shervin Champbell]
```

It has the added benefit that it'll handle multiple quoted strings in the input string if you need it to.

Better still, just use commons-lang, which already does this via [StringUtils.substringBetween()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringBetween%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to find a single string or [StringUtils.substringsBetween()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringsBetween%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to find multiple.

Comment: "_Do you really have to do it with regex? That seems like the hard way_" --> You are using regex ;) Look at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))